# How to remp an existing mapping in a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following function:

```
library(data.table)

data1 <- data.table(KEY = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E"))
keyA <- c("A", "C")
keyB <- c("B", "D")
ifelse(data1$KEY %in% keyA, "Combination 1", ifelse(data1$KEY %in% keyB, "Combination 2", "Combination 3"))
```

However, I was wondering whether there is a simpler and more elegant approach to apply a new mapping to the old keys. In best case I would have one vector containing the mapping structure and then simply apply it across the data.table.

A small note, even though my mapping example is of two "remappings" there can be any number of remappings.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to use a join with a key/val dataset when the number of pairs increases instead of nested `ifelse`

```
keyval <- rbind(data.table(KEY = keyA, Combinations = 'Combination 1'), 
      data.table(KEY = keyB, Combinations = 'Combination 2'))
```

If there are many 'key' objects in the global env, we can get the values of the objects into a `list` and then `stack` it to a two column data.frame

```
keyval <- setNames(stack(setNames(mget(ls(pattern = "^key")), 
        paste0("Combination ", 1:2))), c('KEY', 'Combinations'))
```

And if you are manually entering the mapping, this structure works:

```
keymap = list(
  Combination1 = c("A", "C"),
  Combination2 = c("B", "D")
)

# automatically build keyval from keymap
keyval = rbindlist(
  lapply(keymap, function(x) data.table(KEY = x)), 
  id = "Combinations"
)

# verify there are no dupes in KEY
stopifnot(!anyDuplicated(keyval, by="KEY"))
```

Do a join `on` the 'KEY', create the column 'combin' in 'data1' by assignment (`:=`).  Replace the `NA` elements by assigning it to a new value 'Combination 3'

```
data1[keyval, combin := Combinations, on = .(KEY)]
data1[is.na(combin), combin := 'Combination 3'][]
```

Comment: as a rule I prefer pre-assigning the `combin` column before the join, since `NA` could be a valid value in `Combinations`

Comment: I added the list(name1 = key1, name2 = key2, ...) approach that I find useful, since the OP is working with the special case of mapping to character values. (This would not extend if they were mapping to integers or something.)